# How to convert HTML object's coordinates (top left) to canvas and back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have image object drawn in the canvas element.
I also have a div object in the html (not in canvas).
The aim is to move both objects in canvas and in html together.
In case of div object in HTML, I can use jquery animate function which will move it using top and left css parameters.

By using the step function in animate:
For example like that:

```
animate({width:100}, { duration:1000, step: function(){},
                                      complete: function(){} });
```

I can figure out each position of the moving div element in HTML. But now I have to convert top and left position coords. into the canvas coordinates and move canvas object too.

Moreover I have to know where to move the div element. It should go above another object in the canvas.

So I need to make the function which converts top and left css coordinates into canvas and backwards, from canvas coordinates to top left coordinates in html.

The question is how to do it and may be there is another way to do it, different from what I'm trying to do?